# Is there a word or phrase like "code-switching" that applies to behavior rather than language?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs, terminology

When someone who exists in multiple cultures and/or uses multiple dialects, manners of speaking, etc., switches from one mode of language use to another situationally, they are said to be "[code-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)." I am looking for a word or phrase that is analogous in terms of changing *behavior* situationally—in effect, putting on another persona for a different situation.

The analogy would look like this:

> code-switching:language::________:behavior

Example:

> Bob, a paramedic, gets really riled up when his kids are misbehaving, or when arguing with peers, but when on the job, he instantly _________ to fit the situation when he needs to keep a patient calm, becoming serene in the blink of an eye.

The word or phrase would mean roughly "changes behavior to fit the situation," but be less cumbersome.

Comment: Consider, 'morphs into...'

Comment: In the context of behavior, it seems the phenomenon is referred to as *role transition,* which everyone does all the time with a lesser or greater facility. For a broader treatment of the topic and its context, see here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tsuQAgAAQBAJ

Answer (score 1):

You could use the phrase "switch personas" to describe a person changing their behavior/demeanor to suit their circumstances (and/or achieve an aim).

> Bob, a paramedic, gets really riled up when his kids are misbehaving, or when arguing with peers, but when on the job, he instantly **switches personas** to fit the situation when he needs to keep a patient calm, becoming serene in the blink of an eye.

A "persona," in psychology, is basically one of any number of social "masks" we wear to present ourselves to others in the way that the situation calls for. The definition from Merriam-Webster's online dictionary:

> [persona 2a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persona): an individual's social facade or front that especially in the analytic psychology of C. G. Jung reflects the role in life the individual is playing

An example of the phrase in use:

> Bugs Bunny affords a concrete example of Butler's abstract philosophy of performativity. "Elmer's Candid Camera" reveals gender as anything but candid. The cartoon is metatheatrical, a series of vaudeville schticks, in which Bugs, the master of masculine cool, rapidly **switches personas**: friend, con artist, sadist, athlete, juggler, victim, pious advocate against cruelty to animals, and enraged object of Elmer's alleged homosexual advances.

[Source:](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=tXF-r13HxaQC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22switches+personas%22&source=bl&ots=0A7cWV_lpR&sig=RSQPpY3aTk2CaNIIeV6Gu0fu8rk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22switches%20personas%22&f=false) *David Mamet and American Macho* by Arthur Holmberg

The usage example is analyzing the behavior of a fictional character (Bugs Bunny), but it applies equally well to real-life behavior in people--the switching (changing) of personas to play our assigned role in a social situation.

Answer (score 1):

Bob, a paramedic, gets really riled up when his kids are misbehaving, or when arguing with peers, but when on the job, he instantly **shifts**  to calm first responder mode [or **shifts gears** to fit the situation when he needs to keep a patient calm, becoming serene in the blink of an eye.]

Answer (score 1):

While not a verb, people who do this can be called a *Zelig* after Woody Allen’s mockumentary of the same name.
Defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zelig) as

> ***Zelig***: A person who is able to change their appearance, behaviour, or attitudes, so as to be comfortable in any situation.
>   *‘he has become a veritable Zelig of high technology, burrowing into every information industry nook’*

Answer (score 0):

I would use **transform**:

> Make a marked change in the form, nature, or appearance of.
>
> - *‘he wanted to transform himself into a successful businessman’*
>
> Undergo a marked change.
>
> - *‘In that single moment Susan transformed into a professional gearing up to draw and hold the attention of thousands of viewers.’*
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transform)</sub>

---

A similar word you could also use is **adapt**.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of [Multiple Personality Disorder](http://www.scienceclarified.com/Ma-Mu/Multiple-Personality-Disorder.html), the word **switching** is often used to describe transitioning from one "alter" to another. But, this wouldn't necessary have general application.